# Laravel not recognizing input file when $validation->fails()

Tags: validation, file-upload, laravel-4

I am using dropzone.js to upload files. Whenever $validation->fails()==true, my response::make breaks with the following error:

***"Call to a member function first() on a non-object","file"***

**Code:** 
     public function uploadPhotosAction()
    { 
        if(Input::file('file')){
         $input = Input::all();
          $rules = array(
              'file' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|max:5120|min:265', //Only allow files of the type "image" no smaller than 256 kb and no larger than 5 mb
          );
          $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

```
      if ($validation->fails())
      {
        return Response::make($validation->errors->first('file'), 400);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using  `$input = Input::file('file')` instead of  `$input=Input::all()`

I recomend you to read the docs http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files

Answer (score 0):

It's a method not property, so simply this:

```
return Response::make($validation->errors()->first('file'), 400);
```